# Capistrano fails to delete folders/files created by Apache

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, php, file-permissions, capistrano

### Problem

Capistrano deploys a web application via SSH using `deploy` user.
Apache/PHP runs under typical `www-data` user.

Web server is creating cache files and folders at runtime inside the app path. Example:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 71758 Apr 29 14:33 /var/www/site.com/releases/20140429183204/cache/twig/9e/dd/fd353a4ff2520b59144be49f4a6e.php
```

Capistrano `deploy:cleanup` attempts to delete olders releases, which contains theses cache files but fails since user `deploy` has no write permission on the cache files.

Error reported:

```
cannot remove `/var/www/site.com/releases/20140429183204/cache/twig/9e/dd/fd353a4ff2520b59144be49f4a6e.php' : Permission denied
```

### Usual solution, ACL

My usual solution for this was to set `deploy` in `www-data` group and `www-data` in `deploy` group and set ACLs so new files/folders always get group-write rights.

**My current server filesystem doesn't support acl...**

### Attempted solution, sticky bit

My attempt was to set a sticky bit on the whole app folder. This was attempted while both users are in the other's group.

```
chmod -R g+rwsx /var/www/site.com
```

This works well for new files, but sticky bit doesn't propagate to new folder (which is my problem)

### tl;dr

How to set up permissions so Capistrano(via SSH with user `deploy`) delete files and folders created by Apache with user `www-data`.

Comment: What version of capistrano are you using?

Comment: Capistrano 2.15.5. Does Cap 3.x handles this differently?

Answer (score 0):

Best solution so far is to use the PHP [umask](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.umask.php) function at the beginning of each script.

```
# Make sure all files written are writable by group. 
# Also execute bit so directory's content is listable
umask(0002);
```

This ensure all files and folders created *under normal circumstances* have group-write permission and execute bit so content is list-able.

Yet this could cause problems with libraries ignoring the *umask* and applying permissions manually.